# After installing expo in a bare-bone react native project, I get this error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

After installing expo in my react native project, when I try to create a release build using this command `./gradlew bundleRelease` I get the following error. Is someone experiencing this?

```
> Task :expo:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (16, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (30, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (57, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (63, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/myuser/codebase/myApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity:
  public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':expo:compileReleaseKotlin'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:129)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:173)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:168)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:87)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:530)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:455)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:376)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:340)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:494)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:479)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:462)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$400(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:105)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:251)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$executeOperation$0(ExecuteStep.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeOperation(ExecuteStep.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:72)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:176)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:25)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$3.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:286)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:183)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:183)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue (introducing expo in an existing project). Downgrading from expo@43.0.1 to 40.0.0 fixed it.
I didn't try yet intermediary versions. (I had a project running with expo 40.0.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).